# Cycle index for $S_2\times S_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, coloring, permutation-cycles

I am trying to determine the cycle index polynomial of $S_2\times S_4$, for the purpose of finding colourings. This is what I have tried:

I computed the polynomials for $S_2$ and $S_4$:

$$Z_{S_4}(t_1,\dots ,t_4)=\frac{1}{4!}\left(6t_4^1+8t_3^1t_1^1+3t_2^2+6t_2^1t_1^2+t_1^4\right)$$

$$Z_{S_2}(s_1,s_2)=\frac{1}{2!}\left(s_1^2+s_2^1\right)$$
where $t_i^k$ indicates the presence of $k$ cycles of length $i$ in some cycle class. From what I can see, 'multiplying' should be done using an operation $\cdot$ likewise:
$$t_i^n \cdot s_j^m = w_{\text{lcm}(i,j)}^{mn\cdot\text{gcd(i,j)}}$$
where $w_k$ are variables for $Z_{S_2\times S_4}$, and if there are several variables as a product (e.g. $t_3^1 t_1^1$) then multiplying by something else, we do pairs separately and multiply, for instance:
$$t_3^1t_1^1\cdot s_1^2=(t_3^1 \cdot s_1^2)(t_1^1\cdot s_1^2)=w_3^2w_1^2$$
Applying this to the product of both polynomials I get:

$$Z_{S_2}(s_1,s_2)\cdot Z_{S_4}(t_1,\dots,t_4)=\boxed{\frac{1}{48}\left(w_1^8 +  6 w_1^4 w_2^2 + 13 w_2^4 + 8 w_1^2 w_3^2 + 8 w_2 w_6 + 12 w_4^2\right)}$$

**Correction** I miscalculated so have updated. As mentioned in a comment below, I interpreted the technique as, if I set all the $w_i$ to $C$, then letting $C=$ some number of colors, giving:

$$Z_{S_2\times S_4}(C,\dots,C)= \frac{1}{48}\left(C^8 + 6C^6+21C^4+ 20C^2\right) $$

This should evaluate to the number of colorings of $2\times 4$ tiles, up to row and column permutation. It works for $C=2,3$ (we get $22, 267$) but fails at $C=4$ where I get $1996$ instead of $1870$.

Would love it if someone could point me in the right direction. Trying to teach myself and I think I've misunderstood how this is meant to work...

Comment: Where are you getting the $1870$ value? Are you trying to compute colorings with exactly four colors rather than at most four colors selected from a set of four? That sequence is $1, 20, 204, 1056, 2850, 4080, 2940, 840, 0, \ldots$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In trying to  compute $Z(S_2\times S_4)$ we use  the two possibilities
from

$$Z(S_2) = \frac{1}{2} (s_1^2 + s_2^1).$$

We also have

$$Z(S_4) = 
\frac{1}{24}
(t_1^4 
+ 6 t_1^2 t_2
+ 8 t_1 t_3
+ 3 t_2^2 
+ 6 t_4).$$

Now to compute the product of $s_p^n$ and $t_q^m$ we consider two cycles
of length $p$ and $q.$ These yield $p\times q$ pairs and we seek the
factorization into cycles of the joint action on these pairs of  $s_p$
and $t_q$, with $s_p$ acting on the first component of the pair and $t_q$
the second. The order of such a pair is $\mathrm{LCM}(p,q)$ which
divides the $pq$ pairs into $pq/\mathrm{LCM}(p,q) = \mathrm{GCD}(p,q)$
cycles. For the first  cycle we have $n$ possibilities and for the
second, $m$ possibilities, for a total of $m \times n$ pairs of cycles
$s_p$ and $t_q.$ Therefore  the product operation is given by

$$s_p^n \cdot t_q^m = 
a_{\mathrm{LCM}(p,q)}^{mn\times \mathrm{GCD}(p,q)}.$$

Now for $s_1^2$ we are fixing the two rows of the board and permuting
the columns, hence it  suffices to square terms from $Z(S_4)$ to get

$$\frac{1}{48}
(a_1^8 
+ 6 a_1^4 a_2^2
+ 8 a_1^2 a_3^2
+ 3 a_2^4 
+ 6 a_4^2).$$

For  $s_2$ we  have the  rule that  pairing with  $t_q$ (we  have $2q$
pairs) where $q$ is odd has  order $2q$ and hence yields $a_{2q}$, and
order $q$ when $q$ is even  and hence yields $a_q^2$. Processing these
in sequence we obtain

- $t_1^4$: $q=1$, total is $a_2^4$
- $6 t_1^2  t_2$: $q=1$, $a_2^2$ and $q=2$,  $a_2^2$, total is $6
  a_2^4.$
- $8  t_1 t_3$:  $q=1$, $a_2$ and $q=3$,  $a_6$, total is  $8 a_2
  a_6$
- $3 t_2^2$: $q=2$, $a_2^2$, total is $3 a_2^4$
- $6 t_4$: $q=4$, total is $6 a_4^2.$

This contribution is

$$\frac{1}{48} (10 a_2^4 + 8 a_2 a_6 + 6 a_4^2).$$

Collecting the two pieces we get

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
Z(S_2 \times S_4) =
\frac{1}{48}
(a_1^8 
+ 6 a_1^4 a_2^2
+ 8 a_1^2 a_3^2
+ 13 a_2^4 
+ 8 a_2 a_6
+ 12 a_4^2).}$$

We normally would not do this computation with pen and paper but use a
CAS instead.  With Maple  as shown below  we can treat  the case  of a
$2\times N$ board and get e.g. for $N=6:$

$$Z(S_2\times S_6) =
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{12}}{1440}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a
_{{2}}}^{2}}{96}}+1/36\,{a_{{1}}}^{6}{a_{{3}}}^{2}+1/
32\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{4}\\+1/16\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{
{4}}}^{2}+1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2
}+{\frac {91\,{a_{{2}}}^{6}}{1440}}+1/10\,{a_{{1}}}^{2
}{a_{{5}}}^{2}\\+1/9\,{a_{{2}}}^{3}a_{{6}}+3/16\,{a_{{2}
}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}+1/36\,{a_{{3}}}^{4}+1/10\,a_{{2}}a
_{{10}}+{\frac {7\,{a_{{6}}}^{2}}{36}}.$$

We  obtain for  two  colors with  a $2\times  N$  board the  following
sequence of inequivalent colorings:

$$3, 7, 13, 22, 34, 50, 70, 95, 125, 161, \ldots$$

which points us to  [OEIS A002623](https://oeis.org/A002623) where the
problem statement by  OP is cited as a definition  of the sequence, so
we have the correct result.

The Maple code for this goes as follows:

```
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
local l;
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_cycleind_board2N :=
proc(N)
option remember;
local sidx, idx, sl, q;

    sidx := pet_cycleind_symm(N);

    sl := [seq(a[q]=a[q]^2, q=1..N)];
    idx := 1/2*subs(sl, sidx);

    sl := [seq(`if`(type(q, odd),
                    a[q] = a[2*q],
                    a[q] = a[q]^2),
               q=1..N)];
    idx + 1/2*subs(sl, sidx);
end;

Q :=
proc(N, C)
option remember;
local sl, q;

    sl := [seq(a[q] = C, q=1..2*N)];
    subs(sl, pet_cycleind_board2N(N));
end;
```

Note that we can compute a closed form of the count of colorings using
a $2\times N$ board and $C$  colors with the exponential formula which
gives the OGF of the cycle index $Z(S_N)$ of the symmetric group.  The
formula states

$$Z(S_N) = [w^N]
\exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1} a_\ell \frac{w^\ell}{\ell}\right).$$

Now for the first term we square the $a_\ell$ and replace by the count
$C$ of the number of colors to get

$$\frac{1}{2} [w^N]
\exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1} C^2 \frac{w^\ell}{\ell}\right)
= \frac{1}{2} [w^N]
\exp\left(C^2 \log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [w^N] \frac{1}{(1-w)^{C^2}}
= \frac{1}{2} {N + C^2-1\choose N}.$$

For the second term we double the length of odd cycles and square even
ones:

$$\frac{1}{2} [w^N]
\exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1} a_{2\ell}^2
\frac{w^{2\ell}}{2\ell}
+ \sum_{\ell\ge 0} a_{4\ell+2}
\frac{w^{2\ell+1}}{2\ell+1}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [w^N]
\exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1} C^2
\frac{w^{2\ell}}{2\ell}
+ \sum_{\ell\ge 0} C
\frac{w^{2\ell+1}}{2\ell+1}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [w^N] \frac{1}{(1-w^2)^{C^2/2}}
\exp\left(C \sum_{\ell\ge 0} 
\frac{w^{\ell}}{\ell}
- C \sum_{\ell\ge 0} 
\frac{w^{2\ell}}{2\ell}
\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [w^N] \frac{1}{(1-w^2)^{C^2/2}}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^C} (1-w^2)^{C/2}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [w^N] \frac{1}{(1-w^2)^{C(C-1)/2}}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^C}.$$

Collecting the two pieces we get the following closed form:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2} [w^N]
\left[ \frac{1}{(1-w)^{C^2}}
+ \frac{1}{(1+w)^{C(C-1)/2}}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^{C(C+1)/2}} \right].}$$

Extracting coefficients yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\begin{gather}
\frac{1}{2} {N + C^2-1\choose N} \\
+ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^N
{C(C-1)/2-1+q\choose q} \times (-1)^q
\times {C(C+1)/2-1+N-q\choose N-q}.
\end{gather}}$$

We get in particular for two colors the
generating function is the following:

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{(1-w)^4}
+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{(1+w)(1-w)^3}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1+w}{(1+w)(1-w)^4}
+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{1-w}{(1+w)(1-w)^4}
= \frac{1}{(1+w)(1-w)^4}.$$

Converting to partial fractions, we get

$$\frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{1+w}
+ \frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{1-w}
+ \frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{(1-w)^2}
+ \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(1-w)^3}
+ \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(1-w)^4}.$$

Extracting the coefficient we have

$$\frac{1}{16} (-1)^N
+ \frac{1}{16}
+ \frac{1}{8} {N+1\choose 1}
+ \frac{1}{4} {N+2\choose 2}
+ \frac{1}{2} {N+3\choose 3}$$

for a total of

$$\frac{1}{12} N^3 + \frac{5}{8} N^2 + \frac{17}{12} N
+ \frac{(-1)^N}{16} + \frac{15}{16}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry I miscalculated/got mixed up, I also get $Z_{S_2\times S_4}(a_i)=1/48 (a_1^8+ 6a_1^4a_2^2+13 a_2^4 + 8 a_1^2 a_3^2 + 8 a_2 a_6 + 12 a_4^2)$. What I'm confused by, is that I thought if I set all $a_i$ to $c$, giving $1/48(c^8 + 6c^6+21c^4+ 20c^2)$ then putting $c=$ number of colours, should give me the number of colourings I'm looking for (in this case $2\times 4$ board up to row and column permutations). It works for $c=2$ and $c=3$ ($22$ and $267$) but for $c=4$ gives $1996$ rather than $1870$.

Comment: I also get $1996$ so that looks correct.

Comment: Oh strange... I'll find the OEIS that made me think it should be $1870$, hold on :)

Comment: I get the sequence $$1, 22, 267, 1996, 10375, 41406, 135877, 384112, \ldots$$ which is [OEIS A128766](https://oeis.org/A128766).

Comment: OEIS does not have an entry for $22,267,1870,\ldots$

Comment: I must've made a mistake somewhere, sorry about that. Thank you for all the help